# How to correctly use sequence tag when validating XML?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm trying to validate XML as shown below. I have 3 elements `name`, `age`, `address` that must be declared in that order (hence the sequence tag). The job element however should be allowed to be displayed anywhere (ie: before or after this sequence of elements). Is this possible using XSD validation? At the moment I can only get it to accept it being added after these elements as that is where it falls in the sequence. I have also tried mixing `xs:choice` with `xs:sequence` but no success.

```
<xs:complexType name="PersonNode">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="tns:StringLabel"/>
        <xs:element name="age" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="job" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="valid" type="xs:boolean"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that `job` doesn't have to be optional, you can use `xs:choice` to achieve your desired constraint as follows:

```
  <xs:complexType name="PersonNode">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="tns:StringLabel"/>
        <xs:element name="age" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="job" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="job" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="name" type="tns:StringLabel"/>
        <xs:element name="age" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="valid" type="xs:boolean"/>
  </xs:complexType>
```

However, this assumes that `job` is required to be in one place or the other; otherwise, this will run afoul of Unique Particle Attribution.  [*Update: Don't miss C. M. Sperberg-McQueen's idea in the comments for allowing `job` to be optional.  It cleverly skirts UPA by dedicating the second choice to the leading `job` case while letting the first choice cover both the no `job` and the trailing `job` case.*]

All things considered, I would recommend that you go with your original approach and drop the requirement that `job` be allowed to appear in two different places in the content model of `PersonNode`.   I can't tell you how many times I've seen people struggle with allowing elements to be unordered for purely theoretical concerns that only serve to complicate matters in practice.

Comment: To make `job` optional here without tears or gnashing of teeth, one could add `minOccurs="0"` to the first occurrence of `job` in the content model (the one following `address`) but not the other one.  But it would be better to follow the advice given here:  unless the position of `job` conveys some concrete information, assign it a fixed position.

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen: Excellent!